# Running gdb on xv6-riscv-fall19

Tags: linux, terminal, gdb

So I follow the commands on [the website](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/lec/gdb_slides.pdf).

I open one windows and I used the command: `sudo make qemu-gdb`. And it asked me to use another terminal  to start gdb.

When I used the gdb provided by the Linux system. It shows this error message:

```
.gdbinit:2: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined item: "riscv:rv64".
```

What should I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb instead of gdb. It would be installed in your system when you install riscv-gnu-toolchain specified in xv6 site.

Comment: really helpful!, I use gdb by default and it gives me something like `(gdb) run
Starting program:
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb)
`, then I came here and find my answer, thx!

Answer (score 1):

use `/usr/bin/gdb-multiarch` instead

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? Why does this address the problem? How would this work?

Comment: it seems like only multi-arch version support riscv, did you try for it?

Comment: it won't work either, this is the info `.gdbinit:2: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined item: "riscv:rv64".
` in Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 1):

riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb didn't come with the riscv-gnu-toolchain for me.
Using gdb-multiarch in ubuntu 18 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your gdb version should be 8.3 and later

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `gdb` with `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` when you are following the textbook and you should be good to go.

You can also run

```sh
riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb --version
```

to check the availability of this command. If something is not right, see [this](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/tools.html) page to re-install the toolchain. (Remember to `make clean` before re-making to clean the temporary files.)